# Error code 400 on http request PUT request

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient

I am trying this code but I am get Status Code 400, Bad request. I am trying to PUT data using json in a text file.

When I try this using postman it works fine when I put the below json in Body and set Type to PUT.

Json in File:

```
{
    "objectPath": "/TestData1/TestData2/_C++TestData3/TestData6.TestData8:TestData15",
    "functionName": "Test_FuncCall",
    "generateTransaction": true
}
```

Console app .NET 4.7.2

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        JObject data = JObject.Parse(File.ReadAllText(@"D:\data.txt"));


        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:5555/");

        var content = new StringContent(data.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");


        var response = client.PutAsync("test1/test2/test3", content).Result;

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            Console.Write("Success");
        }
        else
            Console.Write("Error");
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: You have to post the action test1/test2/test3

Comment: What's your api code?

Comment: @Serge What do you mean? do I have to POST, then PUT?

Comment: @D-Shih What you mean by API code? The server is not mine

Comment: @Decoder94 You have to include in your question http://localhost:5555/test1/test2/test3 action code

Comment: @Serge this is all the code I have which suggect to me am missing something? I am new to this domain. The server does not belong to me, I am PUT data to a third party API