# How to asyncronously get response WebRequest .NET 4.7.2

Tags: c#

How can I get the response in this function instead of it going off to an event handler with the event handler I dont know which message belong to which comand i send where as if wait in this function I should get the json back

```
void SendReq()
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(requestURIString);
    request.UserAgent = "Test App";
    request.Method = method;
    
    if (body != "")
    {
         p_CurrentAPIRequest = body;
        request.BeginGetRequestStream(new AsyncCallback(GetRequestStreamCallback), request);
    }
    else
        request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(GetResponseCallback), request);
    
    allDone.WaitOne();

    return "return response"
}
```

Comment: Which version of .net framework or .net you are using ?

Comment: @dotnetstep in title now

Comment: `var response = await request.GetResponseAsync()` ?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webrequest.getresponseasync?view=netframework-4.7.2#system-net-webrequest-getresponseasync

Comment: You mean synchronously not asynchronously.

Comment: @Pieterjan I tried that below `allDone.WaitOne();` and I am getting null in response

Comment: @rabbit I am not sure to be honest I want to send as much command as i can at  any one time but make sure the right data comes back to every call I make

Comment: Don't use `WebRequest`, it is old, awkward and legacy. Use the modern `HttpClient` instead.

Comment: @Fred its the only thing I can get to work :) I have tried HTTPclient but its giving me error 400. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71310667/error-code-400-on-http-request-put-request)

Comment: @Decoder94 then you're using it wrong. Use the `PutAsJsonAsync` instead of `PutAsync` method else you're sending the wrong Content-Type which is why you get 400 error.

Answer (score 0):

[Here's a code snippet](https://github.com/PieterjanDeClippel/Chatprogramma35/blob/master/Server/Form1.cs#L40) from many years ago demonstrating how you should use `Begin.........` async operations (.NET 3.5 style).

```
myTcpListener.BeginAcceptSocket(new AsyncCallback(AcceptSocketCallback), state);

private void AcceptSocketCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    ...
    chatClient.BeginRead();
}
```

starts the async operation. When done, `AcceptSocketCallback` is invoked. This in turn starts another [async operation](https://github.com/PieterjanDeClippel/Chatprogramma35/blob/1aac6153841d7829ff8c4d25d2f021c7ed949548/Server/ConnectedClient.cs#L27)

```
public void BeginRead()
{
    networkStream.BeginRead(receivedData, 0, bufferSize, new AsyncCallback(NetworkStreamReadCallback), stream);
}
```

with its own callback

```
private void NetworkStreamReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    ...
}
```

`if (body != "")` there's no point in doing this.

`return "return response"` If you're using `BeginGetResponse()`, you're not returning any value from this method, so this should be removed.

Disclaimer, I'm not going to spoon the solution into your mouth. You should be able to solve your problems using the code provided here...